# Terminal will not accept password after removing Extension Settings from touchbar

Tags: terminal, password, touch-bar

I wanted to remove Extension Settings, which I intensely dislike, from the Touch Bar, and found the excellent answer to Removing "Configure in: Extensions Settings" from Quick Actions on Touch Bar in OS Sonoma 14.1.  It said to run `sudo killall -9 TouchBarServer` from Terminal, and it will then prompt for a password.  I did that and it worked perfectly.

However, shorty thereafter, Extension Settings was back again, I don't know why.  I went back to Terminal and repeated what I had done before, but this time it refused to accept the same password it had accepted shortly before (I was extremely careful by the 3rd try).  I even changed the password and typed the new one in with the greatest care, with the same result.

What could be happening here (and is there any other way to make the Touch Bar black?)

Comment: Can you please link to the instructions you used?